# How To Find SVN on my Mac

Tags: macos, mac, bash, svn, finder

I'm very wet behind the ears on my Mac as I'm a windows developer.

I'm trying to find out if I have SVN installed and where it is but I cannot even figure out this basic task.

I've got a terminal window open (is this using bash?) and according to things I've read it could be in /usr/local/bin but I cannot even seem to get the terminal app to change to this directory.

Can I view any of this with finder as I cannot seem to even locate it using Finder.

I feel extremely dumb right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most probably you won't have SVN installed by default. But you can check by running this in your terminal:

```
$ whereis svn
```

Generally speaking you can do that for any executable

```
$ whereis cat
cat: /bin/cat /usr/share/man/man1/cat.1.gz /usr/share/man/man1p/cat.1p.gz
```

When not installed:

```
 $ whereis nothing
 nothing:
```

Comment: I've installed Xcode so I think it was installed with that as `whereis svn` returned `/usr/bin/svn`

Comment: Urgh, so many questions ...

Comment: It's installed actually. Run `$ svn --version` to test it.

Comment: Indeed, I ran that and got 1.6 back and now I'm in the process of updating this but run into another problem and I've just posted a question about that.

Answer (score 0):

Command for terminal (do not enter $-symbol):

```
$ which svn
```

For me the path to shortcut of SVN was at `/usr/local/bin`. When I right clicked to show the original path I found my SVN executable at `/usr/local/Cellar/subversion/1.14.1/bin/svn`

macOS Big Sur